# How do I extract an element from a list in python3? I've tried, but what I've done is not working

Tags: python, list

I've (supposedly successfully) extracted rows of values from a table in a SQLite3 database, but I get "KeyError: 16" when attempting to extract a value from a row to save in a variable. The row, being a list, should contain 19 elements. Why do I get a KeyError:16 ?

I tried referring to a row value in the same way in a prior coding problem set, and it worked fine. What's wrong here?

Here's the code snippet of the function with the problem:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method=="POST":
        #cancerlist is the name of the html select menu,
        #and below I'm getting the type of cancer the user 
        #selected, and saving it in a variable called selection.
        #based on the selection, I want to return a different html
        #file for each selection, to display info about medications
        #used for that type of cancer, and their side effects.
        selection = request.form.get("cancerlist")
        if selection == "breast cancer":
            #declaring lists to use later.
            side_effects_list=[]
            percentages_one=[]
            rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM 'breast cancer'")
            for row in rows:
                i = 3
                while len(row) > 0:
                    #make list of side effects percentages for 
#breast cancer medications, by appending percentages to a list,
                    #starting from the side effects, and not 
#appending the id, medication name, and dosage form, which are
#in the last 3 columns of the table.
                    percent = row[len(row)-i]
                    percentages_one.append(percent)
                    i+=1
                    if len(row) == 0:
                        side_effects_list = ("cardiac side 
effects", "hepatotoxicity", "peripheral neuropathy", 
"thrombocytopenia", "alopecia", "headache", "vomiting", "decreased 
appetite", "leukopenia", "anemia", "fatigue", "infections", 
"abdominal pain", "nausea", "neutropenia", "diarrhea" )
                        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                        ax.barh(percentages_one, side_effects_list)
        #I want to plot a graph using side effects of medications 
#on the x-axis and percentage of occurence of the
        #side effects on the y-axis, but I haven't figured out how 
#to do that yet, so part of the code won't make sense,
        #but up till i+=1 I thought was implemented correctly, and 
#do not know why I get KeyError: 16.
        return render_template("breastcancer.html")

    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

I expect this part of the code:

```
percent = row[len(row)-i]
```

to extract an element from the list called "row", and save it in the variable called "percent", however instead I get an error in my terminal stating "KeyError: 16". That doesn't make sense because I have 19 columns in my table, and I've implemented the following:

```
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM 'breast cancer'")
```

to extract the table columns' values and store them as lists of lists called rows. Sorry for the long post, and please excuse any beginner's mistakes I've made. Thank you for your help.

Update: I changed the following:

```
percent = row[len(row)-i]
```

to:

```
percent = row.pop[len(row)-i]
```

and I've gotten these tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 
39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/justforme/application.py", line 45, in 
index
    percent = row.pop[len(row)-i]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.143.110 - - [02/Aug/2019 07:16:00] "POST / 
HTTP/1.0" 500 -
```

Also, when trying:

```
percent = row[len(row)-i]
```

instead of:

```
percent = row.pop[len(row)-i]
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
    1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", 
line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/justforme/application.py", line 45, 
in index
    percent = row[len(row)-i]
KeyError: 16
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.180.145 - - [02/Aug/2019 07:37:49] "POST / 
HTTP/1.0" 500 -
```

Comment: @alkasm thank you for looking into this. it does make sense that it wouldn't remove the element from the list of course, but i still thought it should give me the value at least. I tried row.pop(index), and i got this:                                      percent = row.pop[len(row)-i]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable               so does the row not contain the values i think it contains for some reason?

Comment: A key error typically means that the column name is wrong. Can you print out all the column names to make sure 16 is there? Check to see that there's no additional characters too, I've had problems in the past with spaces in column names

Comment: Yea wait where's the key error at? What line does it point to? Please include the full traceback. I didn't fully read your problem before. If your indexing was wrong you'd get an IndexError, not a KeyError.

Comment: @Novice from what you're saying it seems that I may not understand how extracting  an element from a list in python works. "16" isn't a key. what i meant was that i want to extract the element that is the 16th element in the list, and from what you're saying it seems that it doesn't work that way. i think it would work if i used row["key_name"] to get the value extracted, but i can't really keep entering the key if i want to put this in a while loop, if that makes sense..

Comment: @alkasm as i had just written in response to Novice, i think i don't understand how to extract values from lists properly. i'll edit my question to put the tracebacks there   .

Comment: @Novice , I actually didn't know there was a way to print column names, which in my case are medication side effects. I do want to use the side effects on the x-axis of my bar chart though, so I just typed side effects as a list called side_effects_list to use in the code. (May not be an elegant solution..)

Comment: So, if row were a simple list, then what you did would be exactly how you extract an element from a row. Have you printed rows, or just a single row to make sure it is what you expect? also, checking the type of a variable can be very helpful, and its also very simple. type(row) will work just fine

Comment: Is your `row` even a list? You can check with `type(row)`.

Comment: @Novice Thank you. I tried type(row). So turns out the type for "rows"  is <class 'list'> and the type for "row" is <class 'dict'> . I printed out row and I got a really big dictionary with key:value pairs, but the values in them are of the first row in the SQLite3 table, so at least that part I figured out correctly. I didn't know it would be a huge dictionary though. I thought "row" would be a list, in a list of lists called "rows". (I didn't even know I could print the variables to my terminal. Thank you!) Next I need to figure out how to get the key values extracted from each dictionary.

Comment: @Headcrab turns out my row isn't a list. it's a big dictionary. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Just to add something else, you may want to skip this approach entirely and instead use pandas. Pandas has really nice data structures that are very easy to work with. You can pull data directly from sql (https://datatofish.com/sql-to-pandas-dataframe/) and then manipulate much more easily. Its well worth the effort to learn how to use pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `KeyError` means that `row` isn't a `list`; it's a `dict`. A `list` would raise `IndexError`. See examples:

```
In [1]: a = list(range(4))                                                                               
Out[1]: [0, 1, 2, 3]

In [2]: a[5]                                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4a84d856522b> in <module>
----> 1 a[5]

IndexError: list index out of range

In [3]: b = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}                                                                             
Out[3]: {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}

In [4]: b[16]                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b20f10bd21e5> in <module>
----> 1 b[16]

KeyError: 16
```

To iterate over a dictionary, you can e.g. use the `items()` method:

```
In [5]: for key, value in b.items(): 
   ...:     print(f'key={key}, value={value}') 
   ...:                                                                                                  
key=1, value=a
key=2, value=b
```

**Edit**: 
It is weird though. *Normally* executing a `SELECT` query on an sqlite3 database *should* return a `list` of `tuple`s, so every row would be a `tuple`.

I suspect that in the database connection setup you have a custom `row_factory` installed that makes it into a dict. See this [example](https://pysqlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory) in the documentation.

Comment: Also, just so you know you can get all of the names of a dictionary by typing .keys() after your dictionary name. Might save you typing out the list of side effects ;)

Comment: @Roland Smith Thank you, Roland! Your answer put me on the right track.

Comment: @Novice i actually found that out a little bit ago haha :) I used                             
    keys = list(row.keys())       and                 values = list(row.values()) , printed them, and got the expected results :) Those things allowed me to separate the keys from the values. Thank you! (Next I'll need to figure out how to delete some values from both lists so I can use the lists directly on the y and x axes of a bar chart, or figure out how to only use specific values from the lists on the axes).

Comment: @RolandSmith I saw the updated answer, thank you, Roland!